# I’m trying to humidify my house by evaporating water in a vessel on my wood stove. Will a lidded teakettle produce more or less vapor then a open pot?

Tags: water, evaporation

I found a tea kettle that looks very nice on our wood stove but am thinking that using an open pot would be more efficient at humidifying the air due to the larger exposed surface of the water vs evaporating out of a small spout. Thoughts? Id really like to use the teapot if the difference is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

I also think that the open pot is likely more efficient at humidifying, but instead of spending hours making theoretical models with various assumptions and caveats, this seems like a classic case where it would be faster and more certain to simply do an experiment. Put the open pot and the teapot on the stove with equal amounts of water and see in which one the water level drops fastest.  That container is the one most efficient at putting water into the air.

If it turns out the open pot is faster, you can judge whether the difference is worth using the pot instead of the kettle.